# DateTime.ToString(String, IFormatProvider) doesn't work for Farsi CultureInfo "fa-IR" in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, localization, cultureinfo

The following code works well on a sample .Net Core console application:

```
var result = DateTime.Now.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("fa-IR"));
```

The result is correctly ***27/5/1398*** in this CultureInfo.
But the same code in Xamarin.Forms will result in ***18/8/2019*** which is obviously wrong! I also tried it on Android's MainActivity but got same wrong result.

I tested it on two different Xamarin.Forms projects, one with Xamarin.Forms version *3.6.0.220655* and the other *4.1.0.555618*.

How to get correct result on Xamarin.Forms?

**Update:**

The below line:

```
new CultureInfo("fa-IR").DateTimeFormat.Calendar
```

shows `System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar`! Why??? I expect it to be `System.Globalization.PersianCalendar` for this culture.

**Next try:**
I desperately wanted to set the default calendar of Farsi culture to PersianCalendar this way:

```
new CultureInfo("fa-IR").DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new PersianCalendar();
```

But ran into this exception: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Not a valid calendar for the given culture.` Then after some searching other similar SO questions found this note in official PersianCalendar doc:

> You cannot use a PersianCalendar object as the default calendar for a
>   culture. The default calendar is specified by the CultureInfo.Calendar
>   property and must be one of the calendars returned by the
>   CultureInfo.OptionalCalendars property. Currently, the PersianCalendar
>   class is not an optional calendar for any culture supported by the
>   CultureInfo class and consequently cannot be a default calendar.

Comment: What does `new CultureInfo("fa-IR").DateTimeFormat.Calendar` show? My guess is that either the relevant calendar system isn't supported in Xamarin, or it isn't associated with that culture data.

Comment: @JonSkeet it shows `System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar`. In Console application it returns `System.Globalization.PersianCalendar`.

Comment: So what can we do in either case?

Comment: Well, does Xamarin have `PersianCalendar` at all? Can you use that manually? You could potentially use my Noda Time library instead - that supports the Persian calendar.

Comment: Yes I can access PersianCalendar class in Xamarin.Forms. I'll give it a try to use it manually. I will also try your library. Thanks.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT sadly not yet!

Comment: @JonSkeet This line of code using NodaTime: `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now, CalendarSystem.PersianSimple).ToString("f", new CultureInfo("fa-IR"));` in a .Net Core console application shows `يكشنبه, 3 شهریور 1398 02:36 ب.ظ` which is correct, but in Xamarin.Forms shows `یکشنبه, 3 ژوئن 1398 02:32 ب.ظ`. The problem in latter one is mapping of month where "ژوئن" is a direct translation of "June", but it must have shown "شهریور" like the former one!

Comment: @VahidShir: That would be a problem in the `DateTimeFormatInfo` associated with the culture. You could create your own `DateTimeFormatInfo` instance with the right names, if you want - I'm afraid Noda Time relies on the .NET data for this.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET Core it is supported but not in .NET Framework. You can follow this documentation for convert to Persian Calendar Format:

[PersianCalendar Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.persiancalendar?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I'm using .Net Standard Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: Yes, Xamarin target .NET standart. You can learn more from here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Answer (score 0):

you could change like this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("d"));
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
var dataTime = new DateTime(pc.GetYear(d), pc.GetMonth(d), pc.GetDayOfMonth(d));
var result = dataTime.ToString("dd/M/yyyy", new CultureInfo("fa-IR"));
```

Comment: Why I have to using this strange approach? Why I could not use simple approach like `var result = DateTime.Now.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("fa-IR"));` ?

Comment: @Leo Thanks for your solution. I was already using a library for Farsi culture and it worked just fine. But the problem is I want a universal solution for all languages, without going to probably similar solutions for other similar problematic languages.